# Vim on a remote shell: can't go into "normal mode"

Tags: vim, shell

I'm training on a lab for a certification and after having access to a computer with a remote shell, the only program I can use to edit a file is Vim. The problem is when I type ESC to enter normal mode It writes **^[** and stays in edit mode...

There is also 2 warnings that appears when Vim is starting:

```
Warning: output is not to a terminal
Warning: input is not from a terminal
```

I really don't see how to fix this issue. Any help is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of remote shell technology is the lab using?